# How to find the Redshift Maya API Document?

Tags: python, c++, maya, mel

I'm looking for the `Redshift Maya API Documents`. I've been working on the tools that will automatically create the `Active AOVS Puzzle` matte accordingly to the Object ID Info.

The problem is i couldn't find the `Redshift API Document` specificly right now i'm looking for the command that will list and delete all the `Active AOVs`

Please help ;(

Comment: Did you ask the Redshift support?

Answer (score 0):

I never use redshift, but thanks to the doc here [Doc with AOVs](https://docs.redshift3d.com/display/RSDOCS/Custom+AOVs?product=maya),

I think an AOV is a RedshiftAOV type. So try to list them with :

```
cmds.ls(type='RedshiftAOV')
```

You may have a list of all AOVs. 
And now you can delete the node if the attribute enable is checked.

Edit: Example of the script that you need if I understand your question:

```
all_aovs = cmds.ls(type='RedshiftAOV')
for aov in all_aovs:
    enabled = cmds.getAttr('%s.enabled' % aov)
    if enabled:
        cmds.delete(aov)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You understand my question correctly.
I've read this doc a couple times it's useful but its doesn't contain the API Infomation. What i looking for is API Infomation that explained about the redshift command for Example 'redshiftAddAov' command which i used it to create the Puzzle Matt via python code. 

But the problem is i'm looking for the command that will refresh the Active AOV List The one i found was "redshiftUpdateActiveAovList;" command which work great. But i've to activate the Active AOV once before this command can be used